# vue carousel in mobile shwoing all images at once

Tags: laravel, vue.js, carousel

I have below HTML/JS code

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-FrameView" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FrameView-tab" tabindex="0">
    <div class="product-images img_action_zoom pr_sticky_img kalles_product_thumnb_slide">
        <product-gallery></product-gallery>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="product-gallery-template">
    <div>
    <magnify-image :img-src="images"/>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (() => {
        var galleryImages = @json($images);

        Vue.component('product-gallery', {
            template: '#product-gallery-template',
            data: function() {
                return {
                    images: galleryImages,
                    thumbs: [],
                    galleryCarouselId: 'product-gallery-carousel',
                    currentLargeImageUrl: '',
                    currentOriginalImageUrl: '',
                    currentType: '',
                    counter: {
                        up: 0,
                        down: 0,
                    }
                }
            },

            watch: {
                'images': function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (this.images[0]) {
                        this.changeImage({
                            largeImageUrl: this.images[0]['large_image_url'],
                            originalImageUrl: this.images[0]['original_image_url'],
                            currentType: this.images[0]['type']
                        })
                    }

                    this.prepareThumbs()
                }
            },

            created: function() {
                this.changeImage({
                    largeImageUrl: this.images[0]['large_image_url'],
                    originalImageUrl: this.images[0]['original_image_url'],
                    currentType: this.images[0]['type']
                });

                eventBus.$on('configurable-variant-update-images-event', this.updateImages);

                this.prepareThumbs();
            },

            methods: {
                updateImages: function(galleryImages) {
                    this.images = galleryImages;
                },

                prepareThumbs: function() {
                    this.thumbs = [];

                    this.images.forEach(image => {
                        this.thumbs.push(image);
                    });
                },

                changeImage: function({
                    largeImageUrl,
                    originalImageUrl,
                    currentType
                }) {
                    this.currentLargeImageUrl = largeImageUrl;

                    this.currentOriginalImageUrl = originalImageUrl;

                    this.currentType = currentType;

                    this.$root.$emit('changeMagnifiedImage', {
                        smallImageUrl: this.currentOriginalImageUrl,
                        largeImageUrl: this.currentLargeImageUrl,
                        currentType: this.currentType
                    });

                    let productImage = $('.vc-small-product-image');
                    if (productImage && productImage[0]) {
                        productImage = productImage[0];

                        productImage.src = this.currentOriginalImageUrl;
                    }
                },

                scroll: function(navigateTo) {
                    let navigation = $(`#${this.galleryCarouselId} .VueCarousel-navigation .VueCarousel-navigation-${navigateTo}`);

                    if (navigation && (navigation = navigation[0])) {
                        navigation.click();
                    }
                },
            }
        });
    })()
</script>
```

As you can see in attached image I am getting this kind of rendering during the page load. After complete page load it work fine.

I have tried Lazy-loading as well but that as not worked either.

[image]